# Bootstrap menu does not work properly in mobile view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu

If i click #id links in the menu in mobile view, the menu will stay on top of screen,does not go away, i have click right top button to disable it. first three links are in home page. they have same problems, other pages links work ok, help please.

[[image: Screenshot]]

```
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#sunyong">SUNYONG</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ourteam">OUR TEAM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="parthership.html">PARTNERSHIP</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this template: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/ 

If you are check the javascript code